# A likert scale in HTML

Tags: html, css, scale

I am trying to find code for a likert scale in HTML. I have three questions:

1. I want it to say - Not Guilty on the left and Very Guilty
2. I want it to say - A lot of Damage on the left and No Damage on the Right
3. I want it to say - Not Certain on the left and Very Certain on the Right.

   Does anyone know how to code this?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simplified version of Bill's answer.  You don't need to class each individual `li` if you put it on the whole `ul`.  I'd definitely agree that this is not the appropriate or semantic use of the table element.  This is a *list* of answers.

```css
.likert li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="likert">
  <li> Not Guilty </li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="guilty" value="1" /></li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="guilty" value="2" /></li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="guilty" value="3" /></li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="guilty" value="4" /></li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="guilty" value="5" /></li>
  <li> Very Guilty </li>
</ul>
```

[Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/Z4LYe/)

**Screenshot**:
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

A more "modern" way to get there (without using a table):

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .likert ul
    {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .likert li
    {
        float: left;
        text-align: left;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <ul class="likert">
            <li class="likert"> Not Guilty <input id="radGuiltyStart" type="radio" name="Guilty" value="1" />
            <li class="likert"><input type="radio" name="Guilty" value="2" />
            <li class="likert"><input type="radio" name="Guilty" value="3" />
            <li class="likert"><input type="radio" name="Guilty" value="4" />
            <li class="likert"><input id="radGuiltyEnd" type="radio" name="Guilty" value="5" /> Very Guilty
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
```

NB. I used the following DOCTYPE tag (you *do* always include a DOCTYPE, right?) ;)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

Would radio buttons do the job?

```
 <style type="text/css">
    #likert { text-align:center; }
    #likert td { width: 70px; }
 </style>

  <table id="likert">
     <tr>
         <td><input id="radGuiltyStart" type="radio" name="Guilty" value="1" /></td>
         <td><input type="radio" name="Guilty" value="2" /></td>
         <td><input type="radio" name="Guilty" value="3" /></td>
         <td><input type="radio" name="Guilty" value="4" /></td>
         <td><input id="radGuiltyEnd" type="radio" name="Guilty" value="5" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Not Guilty</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>Very Guilty</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on JJ's answer, it's better if you include labels and put it all on one line.

```
<table id="likert">
     <tr>
         <td><label>Not Guilty<input id="radGuiltyStart" type="radio" name="Guilty" value="1" /></label></td>
         <td><label><input type="radio" name="Guilty" value="2" /></label></td>
         <td><label><input type="radio" name="Guilty" value="3" /></label></td>
         <td><label><input type="radio" name="Guilty" value="4" /></label></td>
         <td><label><input id="radGuiltyEnd" type="radio" name="Guilty" value="5" />Very Guilty</label></td>
     </tr>
...
```